How to hide appBar and bottomNavigationBar when YouTube video is full screen and using StatefulShellRoute?
I am using GoRouter with Stateful Shell Navigation with multiple StatefulShellRoutes (StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack), and several StatefulShellBranches under each.   The shell used for routing depends on the role of the user.
Here is the code for one of those shell routes:
StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
  builder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
    return ScaffoldWithNestedNavigationRole1(
        navigationShell: navigationShell);
  },
  branches: [
    // Home
    StatefulShellBranch(
        navigatorKey: _role1shellNavigatorKeyHome,
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
              path: '/home_role1',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
                    child: HomeScreenRole1(
                        title: 'This is Role 1'),
                  ),
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                    path: 'cars_list',
                    builder: (context, state) => const ItemListScreen(
                          title: 'Cars List',
                          itemType: 'Car',
                        ),
                    routes: [
                      GoRoute(
                        path: 'item/:id',
                        builder: (context, state) {
                          final id = state.pathParameters['id'];
                          return ItemScreen(
                              itemType: 'Car', itemId: id!);
                        },
                      )
                    ]),
                GoRoute(
                    path: 'vehicles_list',
                    builder: (context, state) => const VehiclesListScreen(),
                    routes: [
                      GoRoute(
                        path: ':id',
                        builder: (context, state) {
                          final id = state.pathParameters['id'];
                          return VehicleScreen(vehicleId: id.toString());
                        },
                      )
                    ]),
                GoRoute(
                    path: 'boats_list',
                    builder: (context, state) => const ItemListScreen(
                          title: 'Boats List',
                          itemType: 'Boat',
                        ),
                    routes: [
                      GoRoute(
                        path: 'item/:id',
                        builder: (context, state) {
                          final id = state.pathParameters['id'];
                          return ItemScreen(
                              itemType: 'Boat', itemId: id!);
                        },
                      )
                    ]),
                GoRoute(
                    path: 'theme',
                    builder: (context, state) => const ThemeScreen(),
                    ),
                GoRoute(
                    path: 'youtube',
                    builder: (context, state) => const YoutubeScreen()
                )
              ])
        ]),
    // Health Record
    StatefulShellBranch(
        navigatorKey: _role1shellNavigatorKeyHealthRecord,
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: '/health_record_role1',
            name: 'health-record-role1',
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
                child: HealthRecordScreen(
              title: 'Role 1',
            )),
          )
        ]),
    // Clinic
    StatefulShellBranch(
        navigatorKey: _role1shellNavigatorKeyClinic,
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            path: '/clinic_role1',
            name: 'clinic-role1',
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
                child: ClinicScreen(
              title: 'Role 1',
            )),
          )
        ]),
  ]),


and ScaffoldWithNestedNavigationRole1 is below, where an appBar and bottomNavigationBar are specified:
class ScaffoldWithNestedNavigationRole1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScaffoldWithNestedNavigationRole1(
      {super.key, required this.navigationShell});

  final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

  void _goBranch(int index) {
    print('_goBranch: ${navigationShell.route.branches[0].routes[0]}');
    navigationShell.goBranch(index,
        initialLocation: index == navigationShell.currentIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CommonAppBar(),
      body: navigationShell,
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        selectedIndex: navigationShell.currentIndex,
        destinations: const [
          NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: 'Home1'),
          NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.medical_information), label: 'Record1'),
          NavigationDestination(
              icon: Icon(Icons.local_hospital), label: 'Clinic1')
        ],
        onDestinationSelected: _goBranch,
      ),
    );
  }
}

One of my screens plays a YouTube video using package youtube_player_flutter.   When the user selects the YouTube full screen option, the video orientation changes to landscape (correct behavior), however, the appBar and bottomNavigationBar don't hide.   I want the appBar and bottomNavigationBar to hide when the YouTube video is full screen.
If I rotate the device itself to landscape, the appBar and bottomNavigationBar still don't hide.
I've tried a couple of different approaches to hide the appBar and bottomNavigationBar:
A. SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);

tried calling it in initState(), but it had no affect

B. OrientationBuilder

when device is landscape, set appBar and bottomNavigationBar heights to 0
did not work

Code is below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

class YoutubeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const YoutubeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<YoutubeScreen> createState() => _YoutubeScreenState();
}

class _YoutubeScreenState extends State<YoutubeScreen> {

 late YoutubePlayerController _controller;

 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: '5Peo-ivmupE',
      flags: const YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: true,
        mute: false,
      ),
    );

    // SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final ytPlayer = YoutubePlayerBuilder(
      player: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.amber,
        progressColors: const ProgressBarColors(
          playedColor: Colors.amber,
          handleColor: Colors.amberAccent,
        ),
        onReady: () {
          _controller.addListener(() {});
        },
      ),
      builder: (context, player) => player,
    );

    return OrientationBuilder(
      builder: (context, orientation) {

      if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
        return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            body: ytPlayer
        );
      } else {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: const PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
              child: SizedBox(height: 0),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: const SizedBox(height: 0), 
            body: ytPlayer
        );
      }

    }
    
    );
  }

}

Demo:

Now, I'm stuck.  I can't figure out how to hide the appBar and bottomNavigationBar when the YouTube video is full screen.
Looking for suggestions... anyone know how to accomplish this?
Thank you.
